# JS Regex throwing Maximum call stack size exceeded error

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I have a very long paragraph that I need to compare word boundary to replace matching with the wanted value.

The wanted value will be in many many different patterns. This why I need to have a lot lines of new RegExp to go through the replacement one by one.

```
var paragraph = "german gateway is located at ... Leonardo DA VINci and other some word superman";

paragraph
    .replace( new RegExp("\\b"+ "german gateway" +"\\b", "ig"), "German gateway")
    .replace( new RegExp("\\b"+ "Leonardo DA vinci" +"\\b", "ig"), "Leonardo da Vinci")
    .replace( new RegExp("\\b"+ "some word" +"\\b", "ig"), "some other word")
    .replace( new RegExp
    //continue for at least Few Thousand Rows.

console.log(paragraph);
```

//sample output

```
German gateway is located at ... Leonardo da Vinci and other some other word superman
```

however too many  new RegExp causing js to run into error.

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Is there any way to avoid heavily calling new RegExp while can maintaining exactly the regex rule that I want?

Comment: _"//continue for at least Few Thousand Rows."_ - Do you get payed for lines of code? o.O

Comment: doing this for own usage. just couldn't figure out whether any way or array regex, or have to write it in different way to get the same result without causing call stack error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an object and iterate over the properties. If you need a guaranteed order then you might want to use an array of objects with one object for every replacement.

```js
const paragraph = "german gateway is located at ... Leonardo DA VINci and other some word superman";

const replacements = {
  "german gateway": "German gateway",
  "Leonardo DA vinci": "Leonardo da Vinci",
  "some word": "some other word"
  /* ... */
};

const result = Object.entries(replacements)
                     .reduce((result, replacement) => {
                       const rx = new RegExp("\\b" + replacement[0] + "\\b", "ig");
                       return result.replace(rx, replacement[1]);
                     }, paragraph);
            
console.log(result);
```

And you should definitely escape the variable part in the string you pass to the `RegExp()` constructor.

Comment: this way won't causing creating multiple of new RegExp object?

Comment: Your problem is not the regular expression. Your problem is the chain of `.replace()` calls.

Comment: i see, so call stack size exceeded is caused by too many .replace chaining

Comment: Every function call causes the browser to create a new execution context. For this the old one has to be stored somewhere so that it can be restored when the called function returns the control. "Maximum call stack size exceeded" tells you, that there are too many stored execution contexts (= function calls) - which most likely happens in recursive functions. But in your case its the sheer amount of chained `.replace()` calls.

Comment: hmm i see,  .reduce new thing to me

Comment: It's just one option. This would also work with a `for...in...` loop, or a `for` loop, or `paragraph = paragraph.replace(/*first*/); paragraph = paragraph.replace(/*second*/); ...`, or ...

Answer (score 2):

You can use an "associative" array with keys to search for and values to replace with, build a regex trie out of the search words (keys) and run a single `.replace` with a single regex to find all the phrases and replace them inline with a callback method as the replacement argument to `.replace`.

First, run  `npm install regex-trie` and then use

```js
let paragraph = "german gateway is located at ... Leonardo DA VINci and other some word superman";
const phrases = {"german gateway":"German gateway","Leonardo DA vinci":"Leonardo da Vinci","some word":"some other word"}
let RegexTrie = require('regex-trie');
let trie = new RegexTrie();
trie.add(Object.keys(phrases))
const regex = new RegExp(`\\b${trie.toRegExp().source}\\b`, 'ig')

let getValue = function(prop, obj){
  prop = prop.toLowerCase();
  for(var p in obj){
     if(obj.hasOwnProperty(p) && prop == p.toLowerCase()){
         return obj[p];
     }
  }
}
paragraph = paragraph.replace(regex, (m) => getValue(m, phrases));
console.log(paragraph)
// => German gateway is located at ... Leonardo da Vinci and other some other word superman
```

Here is a JavaScript snippet bundled with the help of `browserify`:

```js
(function(){function r(e,n,t){function o(i,f){if(!n[i]){if(!e[i]){var c="function"==typeof require&&require;if(!f&&c)return c(i,!0);if(u)return u(i,!0);var a=new Error("Cannot find module '"+i+"'");throw a.code="MODULE_NOT_FOUND",a}var p=n[i]={exports:{}};e[i][0].call(p.exports,function(r){var n=e[i][1][r];return o(n||r)},p,p.exports,r,e,n,t)}return n[i].exports}for(var u="function"==typeof require&&require,i=0;i<t.length;i++)o(t[i]);return o}return r})()({1:[function(require,module,exports){
let paragraph = "german gateway is located at ... Leonardo DA VINci and other some word superman";
const phrases = {"german gateway":"German gateway","Leonardo DA vinci":"Leonardo da Vinci","some word":"some other word"}
let RegexTrie = require('regex-trie');
let trie = new RegexTrie();
trie.add(Object.keys(phrases))
const regex = new RegExp(`\\b${trie.toRegExp().source}\\b`, 'ig')

let getValue = function(prop, obj){
  prop = prop.toLowerCase();
  for(var p in obj){
     if(obj.hasOwnProperty(p) && prop == p.toLowerCase()){
         return obj[p];
     }
  }
}
paragraph = paragraph.replace(regex, (m) => getValue(m, phrases));
console.log(paragraph)
},{"regex-trie":3}],2:[function(require,module,exports){
(function (global){(function (){
/*! http://mths.be/jsesc v0.5.0 by @mathias */
;(function(root) {

    // Detect free variables `exports`
    var freeExports = typeof exports == 'object' && exports;

    // Detect free variable `module`
    var freeModule = typeof module == 'object' && module &&
        module.exports == freeExports && module;

    // Detect free variable `global`, from Node.js or Browserified code,
    // and use it as `root`
    var freeGlobal = typeof global == 'object' && global;
    if (freeGlobal.global === freeGlobal || freeGlobal.window === freeGlobal) {
        root = freeGlobal;
    }

    /*--------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    var object = {};
    var hasOwnProperty = object.hasOwnProperty;
    var forOwn = function(object, callback) {
        var key;
        for (key in object) {
            if (hasOwnProperty.call(object, key)) {
                callback(key, object[key]);
            }
        }
    };

    var extend = function(destination, source) {
        if (!source) {
            return destination;
        }
        forOwn(source, function(key, value) {
            destination[key] = value;
        });
        return destination;
    };

    var forEach = function(array, callback) {
        var length = array.length;
        var index = -1;
        while (++index < length) {
            callback(array[index]);
        }
    };

    var toString = object.toString;
    var isArray = function(value) {
        return toString.call(value) == '[object Array]';
    };
    var isObject = function(value) {
        // This is a very simple check, but it’s good enough for what we need.
        return toString.call(value) == '[object Object]';
    };
    var isString = function(value) {
        return typeof value == 'string' ||
            toString.call(value) == '[object String]';
    };
    var isFunction = function(value) {
        // In a perfect world, the `typeof` check would be sufficient. However,
        // in Chrome 1–12, `typeof /x/ == 'object'`, and in IE 6–8
        // `typeof alert == 'object'` and similar for other host objects.
        return typeof value == 'function' ||
            toString.call(value) == '[object Function]';
    };

    /*--------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    // http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-escapes#single
    var singleEscapes = {
        '"': '\\"',
        '\'': '\\\'',
        '\\': '\\\\',
        '\b': '\\b',
        '\f': '\\f',
        '\n': '\\n',
        '\r': '\\r',
        '\t': '\\t'
        // `\v` is omitted intentionally, because in IE < 9, '\v' == 'v'.
        // '\v': '\\x0B'
    };
    var regexSingleEscape = /["'\\\b\f\n\r\t]/;

    var regexDigit = /[0-9]/;
    var regexWhitelist = /[ !#-&\(-\[\]-~]/;

    var jsesc = function(argument, options) {
        // Handle options
        var defaults = {
            'escapeEverything': false,
            'quotes': 'single',
            'wrap': false,
            'es6': false,
            'json': false,
            'compact': true,
            'indent': '\t',
            '__indent__': ''
        };
        var json = options && options.json;
        if (json) {
            defaults.quotes = 'double';
            defaults.wrap = true;
        }
        options = extend(defaults, options);
        if (options.quotes != 'single' && options.quotes != 'double') {
            options.quotes = 'single';
        }
        var quote = options.quotes == 'double' ? '"' : '\'';
        var compact = options.compact;
        var indent = options.indent;
        var oldIndent;
        var newLine = compact ? '' : '\n';
        var result;
        var isEmpty = true;

        if (json && argument && isFunction(argument.toJSON)) {
            argument = argument.toJSON();
        }

        if (!isString(argument)) {
            if (isArray(argument)) {
                result = [];
                options.wrap = true;
                oldIndent = options.__indent__;
                indent += oldIndent;
                options.__indent__ = indent;
                forEach(argument, function(value) {
                    isEmpty = false;
                    result.push(
                        (compact ? '' : indent) +
                        jsesc(value, options)
                    );
                });
                if (isEmpty) {
                    return '[]';
                }
                return '[' + newLine + result.join(',' + newLine) + newLine +
                    (compact ? '' : oldIndent) + ']';
            } else if (!isObject(argument)) {
                if (json) {
                    // For some values (e.g. `undefined`, `function` objects),
                    // `JSON.stringify(value)` returns `undefined` (which isn’t valid
                    // JSON) instead of `'null'`.
                    return JSON.stringify(argument) || 'null';
                }
                return String(argument);
            } else { // it’s an object
                result = [];
                options.wrap = true;
                oldIndent = options.__indent__;
                indent += oldIndent;
                options.__indent__ = indent;
                forOwn(argument, function(key, value) {
                    isEmpty = false;
                    result.push(
                        (compact ? '' : indent) +
                        jsesc(key, options) + ':' +
                        (compact ? '' : ' ') +
                        jsesc(value, options)
                    );
                });
                if (isEmpty) {
                    return '{}';
                }
                return '{' + newLine + result.join(',' + newLine) + newLine +
                    (compact ? '' : oldIndent) + '}';
            }
        }

        var string = argument;
        // Loop over each code unit in the string and escape it
        var index = -1;
        var length = string.length;
        var first;
        var second;
        var codePoint;
        result = '';
        while (++index < length) {
            var character = string.charAt(index);
            if (options.es6) {
                first = string.charCodeAt(index);
                if ( // check if it’s the start of a surrogate pair
                    first >= 0xD800 && first <= 0xDBFF && // high surrogate
                    length > index + 1 // there is a next code unit
                ) {
                    second = string.charCodeAt(index + 1);
                    if (second >= 0xDC00 && second <= 0xDFFF) { // low surrogate
                        // http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-encoding#surrogate-formulae
                        codePoint = (first - 0xD800) * 0x400 + second - 0xDC00 + 0x10000;
                        result += '\\u{' + codePoint.toString(16).toUpperCase() + '}';
                        index++;
                        continue;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (!options.escapeEverything) {
                if (regexWhitelist.test(character)) {
                    // It’s a printable ASCII character that is not `"`, `'` or `\`,
                    // so don’t escape it.
                    result += character;
                    continue;
                }
                if (character == '"') {
                    result += quote == character ? '\\"' : character;
                    continue;
                }
                if (character == '\'') {
                    result += quote == character ? '\\\'' : character;
                    continue;
                }
            }
            if (
                character == '\0' &&
                !json &&
                !regexDigit.test(string.charAt(index + 1))
            ) {
                result += '\\0';
                continue;
            }
            if (regexSingleEscape.test(character)) {
                // no need for a `hasOwnProperty` check here
                result += singleEscapes[character];
                continue;
            }
            var charCode = character.charCodeAt(0);
            var hexadecimal = charCode.toString(16).toUpperCase();
            var longhand = hexadecimal.length > 2 || json;
            var escaped = '\\' + (longhand ? 'u' : 'x') +
                ('0000' + hexadecimal).slice(longhand ? -4 : -2);
            result += escaped;
            continue;
        }
        if (options.wrap) {
            result = quote + result + quote;
        }
        return result;
    };

    jsesc.version = '0.5.0';

    /*--------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    // Some AMD build optimizers, like r.js, check for specific condition patterns
    // like the following:
    if (
        typeof define == 'function' &&
        typeof define.amd == 'object' &&
        define.amd
    ) {
        define(function() {
            return jsesc;
        });
    }   else if (freeExports && !freeExports.nodeType) {
        if (freeModule) { // in Node.js or RingoJS v0.8.0+
            freeModule.exports = jsesc;
        } else { // in Narwhal or RingoJS v0.7.0-
            freeExports.jsesc = jsesc;
        }
    } else { // in Rhino or a web browser
        root.jsesc = jsesc;
    }

}(this));

}).call(this)}).call(this,typeof global !== "undefined" ? global : typeof self !== "undefined" ? self : typeof window !== "undefined" ? window : {})
},{}],3:[function(require,module,exports){
var jsesc = require('jsesc');

/**
 * @module regex-trie
 */
var RegexTrie = (function () {

    "use strict";

    /**
     * The `RegexTrie` class builds a regular expression from a set of phrases
     * added to it. It produces a non-optimised `RegExp` and only represents
     * literal characters; only alphanumeric or underscore ("_") characters are
     * left unescaped.
     *
     * @class RegexTrie
     * @constructor
     */
    var RegexTrie = function () {

        if ( ! (this instanceof RegexTrie) ) {
            return new RegexTrie();
        }

        this._num_phrases_in_trie = 0;
        this._trie = {};

        return this;
    };

    /**
     *
     * Phrases can be added to the trie using `add`. Elements can be wrapped in
     * an array before being added. Only alphanumeric values will be added.
     * Objects, booleans, arrays, etc will all be ignored (failed attempts to
     * add values are silent.)
     *
     * @method add()
     * @param phrase_to_add {array|string|number}
     * @chainable
     */
    RegexTrie.prototype.add = function (phrase_to_add) {

        if ( phrase_to_add instanceof Array ) {
            phrase_to_add.forEach(this.add, this);
        }

        phrase_to_add = this._coerce_to_string(phrase_to_add);

        if ( ! this._is_phrase_valid(phrase_to_add) ) {
            return this;
        }

        // Has this phrase already been added?
        if ( this.contains(phrase_to_add) ) {
            return this;
        }

        var trie = this._trie;

        phrase_to_add.split('').forEach( function (chr) {

            if ( chr in trie ) {

                trie = trie[chr];
                return;
            }

            trie[chr] = {};
            trie      = trie[chr];
        }, this);

        // Set the end marker (so we know this was a complete word)
        trie.end = true;
        this._num_phrases_in_trie++;

        return this;
    };

    RegexTrie.prototype.toRegExp = function () {

        if ( this._num_phrases_in_trie === 0 ) return;

        var result = this.toString();
        return new RegExp(result);
    };

    RegexTrie.prototype.toString = function () {

        if ( this._num_phrases_in_trie === 0 ) return;

        var _walk_trie = function (trie, this_arg) {

            var keys   = Object.keys(trie),
            alt_group  = [],
            char_class = [],
            end        = false; // marks the end of a phrase

            keys.forEach( function (key) {

                var walk_result, insert;

                if ( key === 'end' ) {
                    end = true;
                    return;
                }

                walk_result =
                    this._quotemeta(key) + _walk_trie(trie[key], this_arg);

                // When we have more than one key, `insert` references
                // the alternative regexp group, otherwise it points to
                // the char class group.
                insert = ( keys.length > 1 ) ? [].push.bind(alt_group)
                                             : [].push.bind(char_class);
                insert(walk_result);
            }, this_arg);

            return this_arg._to_regex(alt_group, char_class, end);
        };

        var result = _walk_trie(this._trie, this);
        return result;
    };

    RegexTrie.prototype._to_regex = function (alt_group, char_class, end) {

        var group_has_one_element = function (el) {
                return el.length === 1;
            },
            result = "";

        // Once we've finished walking through the tree we need to build
        // the regex match groups...
        if ( alt_group.length > 0 ) {

            if ( alt_group.length === 1 ) {
                // Individual elements are merged with the current result.
                result += alt_group[0];
            }
            else if ( alt_group.every(group_has_one_element) ) {
                // When every single array in the alternative group is
                // a single element array, this gets flattened in to
                // a character class.
                result += ( '[' + alt_group.join('') + ']' );
            }
            else {
                // Finally, build a non-capturing alternative group.
                result += ( '(?:' + alt_group.join('|') + ')' );
            }
        }
        else if ( char_class.length > 0 ) {
            result += char_class[0];
        }

        if ( end && result ) {

            if ( result.length === 1 ) {
                result += '?';
            }
            else {
                result = '(?:' + result + ')?';
            }
        }

        return result;
    };

    RegexTrie.prototype.contains = function (phrase_to_fetch) {

        if ( ! this._is_phrase_valid(phrase_to_fetch) &&
                this._num_phrases_in_trie > 0 ) {
            return false;
        }

        var trie = this._trie;

        // Wrap the attempts to contains in a try/catch block; any non-existant
        // keys will cause an exception, which we treat as 'this value does not
        // exist'.
        try {

            phrase_to_fetch.split('').forEach( function (chr) {
                trie = trie[chr];
            });

            return ( trie.hasOwnProperty('end') && trie.end === true );
        }
        catch (e) {
            // Fall through
        }

        return false;
    };

    RegexTrie.prototype._coerce_to_string = function (phrase) {

        if ( typeof phrase === 'number' && ! isNaN(phrase) ) {
            phrase = phrase.toString();
        }

        return phrase;
    };

    RegexTrie.prototype._is_phrase_valid = function (phrase) {
        return ( typeof phrase === 'string' && phrase.length > 0 );
    };

    RegexTrie.prototype._quotemeta = function (phrase) {

        if ( ! this._is_phrase_valid(phrase) ) {
            return phrase;
        }

        return phrase
            .replace(/([\t\n\f\r\\\$\(\)\*\+\-\.\?\[\]\^\{\|\}])/g, '\\$1')
            .replace(/[^\x20-\x7E]/g, jsesc);
    };

    return RegexTrie;
})();

module.exports = RegexTrie;

},{"jsesc":2}]},{},[1]);
```

Comment: If your `phrases` can contain terms with special regex metacharacters, you will need to escape them and in case they can appear at the start/end of the search term, you will need to reconsider using word boundaries.

Comment: i'm putting my script to run at chrome console snippet section,   wonder is there any way I can call the regex-trie if this the case.

Comment: @ineedhelp You need to use it with node.js. You are using it, right? Else, see [Client on Node.js: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059580/client-on-node-js-uncaught-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined)

Comment: @ineedhelp I added a snippet that works in the browser using `browserify`. Is it now fine enough?